# How to open dired in another buffer from ido mode?

Tags: emacs

I usually keep two buffers side by side, say `left-buffer` and `right-buffer`.

As I frequently need to check directory structure for the current buffer I am editing (this happens often when I am writing `javascript` files and need to include another script with relative path), I type `C-x C-f` to open `ido` mode and then type `Enter` to open dired.

Problem is, this way the `dired` buffer took the place of my current `left-buffer` which I am working on.

Is there a way to open `ido-mode` in "the other buffer" (here is the `right-buffer`)?

---

**EDIT**
I also have `projectile-mode` `winner-mode` installed. If any of these mode contains ready-command to do so, it will work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable opening the pwd in ido:

```
(setq ido-show-dot-for-dired t)
```

Then you can do e.g. `C-x C-f` and one of the options is `.`, which will open a dired buffer for the pwd.

There's a command `find-file-in-other-window`, bound to `C-x 4 f` and `C-x 4 C-f` by default, that you can use to open any file, including a directory, in another window.

Note that `default-directory` is the directory that ido looks in, not necessarily the directory of `buffer-file-name`, though `default-directory` defaults to that.

Comment: I used `C-x 4 C-f` followed by `RET`, then it worked as expected.